# How Can I send many messages to the same email that owned by specific company in a short time?

Tags: email, rate-limiting

I want to send many messages to the same email that owned by a company Ex: admin@company.com but I don't have the programming background to do it. It's for testing purposes. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

for ($x = 0; $x <= 10; $x++) {
  // the message
 $msg = "First line of text\nSecond line of text";

 // use wordwrap() if lines are longer than 70 characters
 $msg = wordwrap($msg,70);

 // send email
 mail("admin@company.com","My subject",$msg);
}

?>
```

this code will help you in doing this. you just have to replace 10 as per your requirement.